# Как записать данные последне созданного textBox в XML тэг?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

То есть случай такой: У меня в программе 1 встроенный текстбокс. При нажатии на кнопку добавляются еще текстбоксы. Как мне сделать, чтобы записать в тэг XML запись содержащийся в этом текстбоксе?
Ну вот код общий такой:

```
 writer.WriteString = textBox1.Text;
```

Но дело в том, что я не знаю с какого textBox'a он будет брать запись. Мне нужно с последнего. Как это сделать? Думаю тут нужен this. Т.к сами текстбоксы у меня создаются следующим кодом:

```
 this.Controls.Add(new TextBox() {Location = new Point(x, y), Width = 540, Height = 30, Multiline = true});
```

Comment: > Думаю тут нужен this.

А-А-А! Где-то я такое уже видел!

Comment: да да, видел. Ну не покидает меня эта затея. Я ведь создаю подобным образом =/ Помоги разобраться. А то я дошел до середины и тут у меня такое. Я не могу разобраться никак =/ @Flammable

Answer (score 1):

Когда добавляете `TextBox`, запоминайте его в поле класса, вот и всё.

По-хорошему, надо бы запоминать *все* добавленные `TextBox`-ы, вдруг вы их и удалять захотите.

Comment: вот и так и хочу делать. Не получается

Comment: Как вы делаете? Дайте код, который запоминает последний добавленный `TextBox`? Ваш код (`this.Controls.Add(new TextBox()...`) только добавляет, но не запоминает.

Comment: если честно, то над этим я не думал и не знаю как формы сохранять =/ но я хочу все записывать в XML. Попытаюсь поискать в гугле

Comment: @navi1893: О боже, это же просто. Заведите себе поле `TextBox lastTextBox;`, инициализируйте его первым `TextBox`-ом, при создании следующего записывайте его в эту переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Если предполагается, что новый текстбокс всегда добавляется в конец (если есть последний текстбокс, то и какой-то конец у вас тоже есть), создайте список и добавляйте в него ссылки на свои текстбоксы. Для добавления и удаления этих текстбоксов создайте прокси-методы.

Upd.: по-хорошему надо написать кастомный контрол (ListView из текстбоксов) или использовать какой-нибудь готовый аналог, например, DataGridView.

Comment: а попроще как то?)) я новенький в C#. Про прокси-методы не слышал =/ ну а как в XML ссылки ставить?
У меня еще самая главная проблема знаешь что, то что я потом могу удалить например из 5 текстбоксов третий. При этом они совмещатся наверх все, закрывая пробел. А при добавлении нового после 5-го добавится в конец 3-ий =/ И при Load из XML я столкнусь проблемой =/ Вот не могу решить данную проблемму

Comment: Прокси-метод - это метод-обертка для другого метода.
Выкинь все свои текстбоксы и используй DataGridView. То, что ты сейчас пытаешься делать, очень похоже на костыль.

Comment: нет. ListView не поможет. Мне важно оформление. Могу я выложить в Гугл Диск программу, чтобы ты взглянул?

Comment: Тогда написать свой контрол, как я уже предложил.
Конечно, если очень лениво и нужно на один раз, то можно обойтись текстбоксами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно было получать значение из TextBox по его имени, запоминая имя последнего

```
       public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0, n = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   n++;
            this.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Location = new Point(x, y), Width = 540, Height = 30, Multiline = true, Name = n.ToString() });
            y = y + 40; 
        }

        private void Show_Rez_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox control = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find((n).ToString(), true).First();
            MessageBox.Show(control.Text);
        }
    }
```